# Section's and cases

Tags: objective-c

A small issue over here i have 4 sections when i click on the first TableCell of a section (got 4 sections) the NSlogs output is:

```
2012-02-20 20:33:16.870 [8880:c07] 00
```

Can i do something like;

```
if switch(indexPath.row == 0) {

case

} else if(indexPath.row == 1) {

case 

}
```

to 'link' each Tablecell to another function?

The problem is when i use the code ;

```
    case 0: 
        NSLog(@"00");
    break;
```

each first Tablecell of a section gives me the NSlog 00

```
    UIViewController *controller;

     switch(indexPath.row) {

        case 0: 
            NSLog(@"00");
            break;

        case 1: 
            NSLog(@"01");
            break;

        case 2: 
            NSLog(@"02");
            break;

        case 3: 
            NSLog(@"03");
            break;

        case 4: 
            NSLog(@"04");
            break;  
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but your if switch block after "Can I do something like" looks pretty wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    switch(indexPath.row) {
    case 0: 
        NSLog(@"00");
        break;
    case 1: 
        NSLog(@"01");
        break;
    case 2: 
        NSLog(@"02");
        break;
    case 3: 
        NSLog(@"03");
        break;
    case 4: 
        NSLog(@"04");
        break;
    }  
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    switch(indexPath.row) {
    case 0: 
        NSLog(@"10");
        break;
    case 1: 
        NSLog(@"11");
        break;
    case 2: 
        NSLog(@"12");
        break;
    case 3: 
        NSLog(@"13");
        break;
    case 4: 
        NSLog(@"14");
        break;
    }  
}
```

The `if` statement separates the execution path on the `section`, and then `switch` further separates it on the `row`. If the number of sections is significant, you could use an outer `switch` outside of the inner switches.